# Evaluating $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^n}$$

it's easy to see that this series converge by using ratio test, but i have no idea what this series converges to

there might be some problem with $0^0$
if that's the case, i would like to change the lowest bound to $n=1$
or
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^n}$

i'm just curious on how to tackle this kind of problem

Comment: The  [other](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/965814/11619) two [times](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1980698/11619) this was asked no answers came. I guess the only things worth knowing about this series are that it converges by almost any test and that we have the result known as [Sophomore's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Done!